# Chrome V8 engine options

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I know that Chrome V8 Engine has some option that can be set like "command-line" flags using `v8::V8::SetFlagsFromString()`. But where can I find description of the each flag? I did not succeed with googling for this info so far. Does anyone know the place in documentation or some other resource that describes V8 flags?

Comment: Isn't V8 open-source? Have you tried reading the source?

Comment: Yes, V8 is open source, and I even can find the place where these flags are parsed, but even if I find that, how can I undestand the exact meaning and possible values of the each flag? I beleive there should be some official documentation from Google on that.

Comment: Found something in the flag-definitions.h: https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/3.18/src/flag-definitions.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the actual list for your V8 version in a source file `flag-definitions.h`

As I remember, there is a `--help` flag in V8, that prints allowed flags and terminates. You can run `node --v8-options` to see the options for V8 version used in the Nodejs.

There is also https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-flags/blob/master/flags-0.11.md